# Código de correção de erros (repetição)

Tags: python

Tenho algumas dúvidas neste código. Gostaria se alguém me pudesse explicar as funções.

```
from scipy.stats import binom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


r=[2*i+1 for i in range(4)]

def single_bit_error(r, p=0.05):

    return 1-binom.cdf(r//2, r, p)

def message_error(r, p=0.05):

    return 1-(1-single_bit_error(r,p))**256

message_error(12)

plt.semilogy(r, [message_error(i) for i in r])`
```

Comment: Quais são as dúvidas? Você que fez o código? Se não, de onde você o tirou? O que o código deveria fazer?

Comment: o código não fiz, fiz pesquisa na net, é um codigo de correção de erros em telecomunicações, á medida que aumenta o numero de repetições diminui  probabilidade de erro na transmissão, olink é este : https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee126/fa14/lab/Lab11_Viterbi.pdf e as duvidas que tenho é onde está o r//2 e o message_error(12)

Comment: @SergioNunes Ainda não está claro o que você quer. O código também não é dos melhores-- cheio de abreviações, variáveis de uma letra só, funções que fazem tudo em uma linha... difícil entender.

Comment: o que significa r//2 e message_error(12) é só isso

Comment: Pablo Almeida, como posso encontrar um código de correção de erros nomeadamente o de repetição 3,5,7?

Comment: `r//2` é divisão inteira por `2`, garante que o resultado é um `int`. E `message_error` é a função que foi definida no próprio código! Tirando um excerto do código: `def message_error(r, p=0.05):`

Comment: Provavelmente esse código foi executado no console do python. Então, message_error(12) é apenas um teste da função do calculo da probabilidade para r=12. // é o operador de divisão inteira.